# Spring dependency management in a included gradle build

Tags: spring, gradle, dependency-management

I have two independent projects A and B, both using `io.spring.dependency-management` plugins to manage their dependencies. I'm using Gradle composite builds feature to include a project B into A. While both build fine independently if I attempt to build A after including B it seems that the dependency management declaration from B is ignored and it resolves only the versions that were defined in A failing for those which were not: `Extension of type 'RecommendationProviderContainer' does not exist.`

Is it some sort of composite builds deficiency? Any way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency management plugin uses resolution rules to control the dependency versions. Unfortunately, composite builds do not support propagating these rules from one build to another so it cannot be used with composite builds. Adding such support was discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/947) but it was declined in favour of using Gradle's built-in support for version constraints and [Maven boms](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import).